# Task scheduler set to Run whether logged on or not deletes @ symbol

Tags: python, windows, selenium-webdriver, scheduled-tasks

I've run into a problem when trying to run a python selenium script in Task scheduler. The script should log into a wegpage and proceed with scraping. However, when I try to send keys to username field while logging, the symbol @ disappears.

Simply, both commands `username_field.send_keys("sample@gmail.com")` and `username_field.send_keys("sample\u0040gmail.com)` will always output to the field `samplegmail.com` without @.

When the task is set to *Run only when user is logged on*, it works perfectly well whether it would be manual launch, different launch settings in a scheduler, launching from bat file, etc. But when I set it to *Run whether user is logged on or not* the problem occurs.

Any ideas what might be causing it?